# Convert Array From Laravel Collection

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

Im using Laravel 4.2. This maybe quite simple.
When i get result from eloquent model using ->get(), i get this type of result

```
[{"name":"JOHN","tel":"12345"},{"name":"JANE","tel":"67890"}]
```

And I want to convert to this format

```
[["JOHN","12345"],["JANE","67890"]]
```

I've been struggling with this issue and I don't know what exact keyword to search for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [`map()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/collections#method-map) collection method and [`array_values()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php). Just tested this and it's working perfectly:

```
$collection->map(function ($i) {
    return array_values($i);
})->toArray();
```

In 4.2 use `array_map`:

```
array_map(function ($i) {
    return array_values($i);
}, $collection->toArray());
```

Comment: this is laravel 4.2. map() is not available.

Comment: @lucaditrimma I've updated the answer with a solution for 4.2 too.

Answer (score 3):

https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#collections

This may be a shorter way to do as `each` method is availble on collections too, Although `@Alexey` Answer is nice one.

```
$collection->each(function ($i) {
    return array_values($i);
})->toArray();
```